# Отсортировать массив c фотографиями в php

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Добрый день!

Некоторые картинки товаров при скачивании с сайта донора записались не по порядку, например:

```
            [PICS] => Array
            (
                [0] => /upload/medialibrary/683/4906с_white_f4.jpg
                [1] => /upload/medialibrary/f5e/4906с_white_f3.jpg
                [2] => /upload/medialibrary/0dc/4906с_white_f2.jpg
                [3] => /upload/medialibrary/cf2/4906с_white_f1.jpg
            )
```

Но у них у всех в названии картинки есть порядковый номер _f1, _f2, _f3 и т.д. Я знаю, есть такая функция в php **asort()** - сортировка массива по значению, но вот такой косяк - путь перед картинкой (между папкой медиабиблиотеки /upload/medialibrary/ и названием файла картинки) формируется случайным образом. И asort() в чистом виде не срабатывает. Может быть, есть возможность передавать в **asort()** только имя файла или есть подобные функции, где можно такое делать? Из самопала пока вижу такой вариант, как перебирать элементы массива сортируя его по последним 6 символам значения, записывать в отдельный массив значения в правильном порядке и потом выводить. Но мне кажется, что должен быть более изящный способ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример работы](http://ideone.com/uAslaQ)**

```
<?php

$sort_this = array(
    '0' => '/upload/medialibrary/683/4906с_white_f4.jpg',
    '1' => '/upload/medialibrary/f5e/4906с_white_f3.jpg',
    '2' => '/upload/medialibrary/0dc/4906с_white_f2.jpg',
    '3' => '/upload/medialibrary/cf2/4906с_white_f1.jpg'
);

function build_sorter($a, $b) {
    // Имя файла с расширением
    $basename_a = pathinfo($a, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $basename_b = pathinfo($b, PATHINFO_BASENAME)
    // Сравнение строк (Natural order)
    return strnatcmp($basename_a, $basename_b);
}

// Пользовательская сортировка с вызовом callable функции
usort($sort_this, "build_sorter");

print_r($sort_this);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /upload/medialibrary/cf2/4906с_white_f1.jpg
    [1] => /upload/medialibrary/0dc/4906с_white_f2.jpg
    [2] => /upload/medialibrary/f5e/4906с_white_f3.jpg
    [3] => /upload/medialibrary/683/4906с_white_f4.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function cmp($first, $second)
{
    return strcmp(basename($first), basename($second));
}

usort($photos, "cmp");
```

Используется [эта](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) функция для сортировки, [эта](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php) для получения имени файла, а [эта](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcmp.php) для сравнения.